# Edit button not coming on report folder

Tags: reporting, dashboard, reports-folder

I am trying to edit the report folder but edit button isn't coming. Two buttons are coming 'Pin to top' and 'Share'. Is there any permission settings for that ?

Comment: Is it a standard report folder or a custom one?

Comment: its a standard folder